# How to fix a form post redirection issue?

Tags: php, .htaccess

So i have a really simple button in a form that will show some content after the user clicks the button

```
<form class="user" action='/post.php?slug=test' method="POST">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-md ml-0" type='submit' name="GetYourContentButton"><strong>Unlock Content</strong></button></center>
    </form>

if(isset($_POST["GetYourContentButton"])) {
  echo "This is your content";
}
```

The problem is that the official url of the post is `http://localhost/post/test` instead of `/post.php?slug=test` so when the user clicks the button he is redirected to `http://localhost/post.php?slug=test` instead of `http://localhost/post/test`.

For my surprise I always get a "Object not found!" error if i try to change the form in `action='/post.php?slug=test'` so for example `action='/post/test'`does not work.

my htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?post/([^/d]+)/?$ post.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I would discard the form action and include all the necessary code underneath the form and also get rid of the .htaccess rule. You can redirect using javascript inside a php statement if required.

Comment: @SJacks can you give me an example? That way is completely different from what I'm doing...

Comment: A random example probably wouldn't help you too much I need to know what you are trying to accomplish like are you wanting to serve a cookie to a client or submit some data to a table or both or something else? EDIT: I can give you the javascript example if you want.

Comment: @SJacks im trying to do exactly the example i give on the top, when the user clicks in the button the post executes a php function and unlocks a piece of content.

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know what you want to do as you haven't provided the code executed from the form action as per your question, however, try this as an example;

```
<?php
echo "
<form class='user' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='GetYourContentButton' class='btn btn-info btn-md ml-0' value='Unlock Content'>
</form>
";

if(isset($_POST["GetYourContentButton"])) {
// perform your php operations here

// do a redirect afterwards
echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://example.com/somepage');</script>";

// or a timed redirect, this is set to 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
echo "<script>setTimeout(function() {window.open('https://example.com/somepage','_self')}, 2000);</script>";
}
?>
```

HT ACCESS RULES

```
# Disallow non https connections
rewritecond %{HTTPS} !on
rewriterule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# Remove www prefix
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Remove html extension
rewritecond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
rewriterule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]
rewriterule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Remove php extension
rewritecond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
rewriterule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
rewriterule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why is everything in PHP echo's?

Comment: In this case it has to be as it's not a hidden server operation, it's front end code (JavaScript) and for that code to execute it needs to be wrapped in an echo statement. The same would apply if you needed to display some HTML or CSS which worked in conjunction with PHP.

Comment: That's just not true. This just makes everything hard to read.

Comment: My problem is that if I remove the "action=" I get the "Object not found" error after the user clicks the button, the url http://localhost/post/test seems working fine but always gets error when i put it in the form action... seems that only works if I use the url without hiding the php extension and slug...

Comment: @ramenknight I've added some htaccess rules that will help. These will negate the requirement to specify an extension to your files.

Comment: @Rimble it is true in some cases and not true in others, it depends what you need to do with your code. It doesn't matter how the code looks as long as it does its job and only what it intends to accomplish, nothing more and nothing less.

Comment: I added those htaccess rules and im still getting the object not found error :(

Comment: After adding those rules you can navigate to any HTML or PHP file without using the extension. https://example.com/page.php becomes https://example.com/page Please add the rest of your code.

Comment: SJacks thanks but as you can see in my example on the top the url is http://localhost/post/test because its a post using a slug, not a page... And for some reason the form does not work with the SEO friendly url... (I guess is somehow related with htaccess)

Comment: Why not just keep them on the same page? When the button is clicked just consult the table with a select statement and retrieve the info you want. No need for a redirect unless you want to give a separate page for that? If you do need to create a separate page, make one with the same name as the action minus the query string then have some PHP code on that page which detects the query string and processes it.